# Excel VBA macro runs from the VBA editor, but not from the Macro window

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro written in Excel that has now stopped being able to run from the Macro window in the main Excel window. It runs fine when I start it from the editor itself and I have another macro in the same file that also runs fine, and displays properly in the macro window.

Please see the picture.

[image: Macro is not running]

[image]

Why is this happening? It's a pain to run at the moment...

I am running [Excel 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Excel_2013_(v15.0)) if that matters.

[image]

Both subs are stored in the same file, and the one highlighted in the picture above.

---

The issue has weirdly resolved itself now. I did absolutely nothing and it fixed itself. I would still like to know the cause.

Comment: To help us help you, could you a) tell us which macro doesn't work and b) show the code in the failing macro itself since it may be starting then halting for some reason in there?

Comment: The macro does work, if I run it from the VBA editor it runs no problem, but its when I try to run it from the Macro window in excel that excel won't recognise it properly

Comment: Problem has magically resolved itself without me doing anything, very weird. If anyone has an idea I'd still be interested to know why this happened

Comment: This is the subject of a meta question: *[Why are users allowed to accept their own answer, when it does not solve the problem they ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423604/why-are-users-allowed-to-accept-their-own-answer-when-it-does-not-solve-the-pro)*. The answer has now been deleted (only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points).

Answer (score 0):

One is in a module and the other is in "ThisWorkbook".
You need to reference it from ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Both the macros are in the same file, in the "ThisWorkbook" file of the workbook. This problem has only appeared recently it has been working fine up until now

Comment: Presuming they're both the same in terms of `Sub` / `Public Sub`?

Comment: Both public sub. The issue has weirdly resolved itself now, I did absolutely nothing and it fixed itself. would still like to know the cause

Comment: The reason it fixed itself, is because one or more of of the modules were out of sync with the compile cache. Changes to the modules in question can resync the compile cache, and it starts working agian.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because Excel's compiled modules are out of sync with the actual code they contain. This can cause Excel to crash and produce the following event in the *Windows Logs* → *Application* events:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL
Exception code: 0xc0000005
```

You need to recompile all your modules. You can recompile all your modules by either:

1. Modify each module
2. Export all modules, then delete all modules (if it is a Workbook module or a Sheet module, then backup the code it contains and delete the code it contains), then save and close your workbook, then open your workbook and import all modules again (and re-inert the code you backed up into the Workbook module and Sheet modules).

And when you have done that, select the menu *Debug* → *Compile VBAProject* in the VBE window.

Comment: What is VBE? *Visual Basic Editor* (whatever that is)?

Comment: Yes VBE mean Visual Basic Editor.